# I need to connect my existing chrome extension to firebase .could anyone pls suggest a new way?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firebase, firebase-authentication

I've an existing application which uses:

```
$scope.signInGoogle = function(){
var ref = new Firebase(URL);
chrome.identity.getAuthToken({
    interactive: true
}, function(token) {
    localStorage.setItem("token",token);
    if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
        alert(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
        return;
    }

    // Authenticate with Google using an existing OAuth 2.0 access token
    ref.authWithOAuthToken("google", token, function(error, authData) {
      if (error) {
        console.log("Login Failed!", error);
      } else {
        console.log("Authenticated successfully with payload:", authData);
        $state.go("app.profile");
      }
    });
});};
```

Need to know how to use Identity API to login to firebase

Comment: Can you describe better what is the problem with the current code?

Comment: I need to migrate this chrome extension code to firebase 3.0 SDK wherein the documentation for migrating chrome extension is missing for ref.authwithOauthtoken.

Comment: Okay, so you should **clearly spell it out** in the question itself that this is working code for X and you need to migrate it for Y. And if there is relevant documentation, add a link.

Comment: Since you're relatively new, take a look at [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide in general, that's a lot of good advice.

Comment: See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/firebase-talk/HgntKvXHEcY/vu6dCgbuGwAJ